# Select sum columns and then get the lowest value from the columns

Tags: sql, codeigniter, xampp

I have a table with the following columns

[image]

I need to sum the "flat_sewn and the rubber_top columns and then get the smallest value from these two columns. Sometimes these columns will differ.

what I did so far

[image]

This is components of an items and are entered separately into a table and I then need to see haw many was completed by selecting the items from the table and getting the smallest amount.

If someone could guide me in a direction to resolve this, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT
    LEAST(sum(flat_sewn), sum(rubber_top)) AS val
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked but, i need to add other information and join other table so how would i go about doing that

Comment: @WernerPelser, you can add your full requirement in the question with sample data and expected output, or better if you ask it in another question and mark this answer as accepted since it worked for your mentioned case

Comment: @WernerPelser, then please mark it as accepted answer :)